# Android TextView center performance (wrap + layout_gravity vs. match + gravity)

Tags: android, textview

I'm just curious, which method for setting gravity of text inside `TextView` is faster when I want to center the text?

1. to have `<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"\>`
2. or `<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"\>`

And why?